# Output of __android_log_write() not displayed in logcat

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm working on some native c code for Android and trying to output using this code:

```
__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Native", "TEST LOG");
```

logcat within Eclipse and from the command line both fail to show the message, while showing output from calls to Log.d() from the java layer. I've verified with objdump that  __android_log_write() is in the symbol table of my .so file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Native", "TEST LOG");
```

`_print` instead of `_write`

Don't forget to `include <android/log.h>`

Comment: __android_log_print and __android_log_write both exist.  One takes a format string, the other doesn't.

Comment: The answer is obviously wrong, I don't understand why it is marked as "answer"; __android_log_write is legit (see documentation). Android logging is buggy, well, Android is not iPhone, it has a lot of bugs that Google never fixes, if bug doesn't result in huge financial loss, it is not profitable for Google to fix it. Use any custom logging, it is more reliable.